# Why has pandas_datareader stopped retrieving data from IEX and Robinhood APIs

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I have been using pandas_datareader to retrieve stock prices from the IEX and Robinhood APIs for some time without any hitches. However, recently (early this week), my code started failing.

Here's the code and the error:

IEX API

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

end = dt.datetime.today()
start = end - relativedelta(months=20)
data = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', start, end)
```

And the error:

```py
web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', start, end)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-88-2781d4515d5c>", line 1, in <module>
    web.DataReader('MSFT', 'iex', start, end)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 322, in DataReader
    session=session).read()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/iex/daily.py", line 91, in read
    self._get_params(self.symbols))

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 84, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 95, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 155, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError(msg)

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=MSFT&types=chart&range=2y
Response Text:
b'Forbidden'
```

Robinhood API

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt

end = dt.datetime.today()
start = end - relativedelta(months=20)
data = web.DataReader('MSFT', 'robinhood', start, end)
```

And the error:

```py
web.DataReader('MSFT', 'robinhood', start, end)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-90-0a0fc1b0d4ce>", line 1, in <module>
    web.DataReader('MSFT', 'robinhood', start, end)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 391, in DataReader
    session=session).read()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 77, in read
    return self._read_one_data(self.url, self.params)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 86, in _read_one_data
    out = self._get_response(url, params=params).json()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 136, in _get_response
    last_response_text = response.text.encode(response.encoding)

TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

The exact code was working fine until recently. I wonder what changed, and what I can do to correct it.

Comment: What is the request limit on those APIs? 'Forbidden' makes me think you have used your max number of requests.

Comment: Also, according to the IEX site, they made some API changes this month, you should read through those changes and verify that they didn't affect your access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most APIs listed on the pandas_datareader documentation have been deprecated and are no longer effective through the pandas_datareader framework (Yahoo, Google, etc).

However, Tiingo works just fine, at least for now.

To use Tiingo API, you'll first need to sign up for a free account (or paid if you want premium features). You can do that [here](https://api.tiingo.com/). After activating your Tiingo account, you'll receive an API key which you can use to retrieve stock historical data with pandas_datareader (find details [here](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html)).

Answer (score 4):

From https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#stocks

"On June 1, 2019, IEX Group removed all non-IEX data, and certain functionality, according to the schedule. IEX Cloud, a non-Exchange platform, will continue to provide access to third-party data sources."

Looks like you'll need access and secret keys to call their API. I'm looking into this for my python app stock_quote that hit this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the efficient Python library for Yahoo Finance, `yfinance` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)).

You can also find example codes [here](https://medium.com/@jouneidraza522/yahoo-finance-api-to-get-stocks-tickers-data-in-python-c49820249a18) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/free-stock-data-for-python-using-yahoo-finance-api-9dafd96cad2e).